# Is it possible to skip separate object creation in Python OOP and create the object when class function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Is it possible to create an object directly when a class function is called?

```
LONG_PRESS='LONG_PRESS'

class Press(object):

"""docstring for Press"""

    def __init__(self, nr, T):
        super(Press, self).__init__()
        self.nr = nr
        self.T = T

    def Button(self):
        if self.T == 'LONG_PRESS':
        return "Button[BUTTON"+str(self.nr)+"].Press(T_PRESS_LONG);"

print(Press.Button(2,LONG_PRESS))
```

i want to skip the part where the object is created:

`Press1=Press(2,LONG_PRESS)
print(Press1.Button)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you're after `Press(2, LONG_PRESS).Button()`. Either way, you don't need to assing the instance to a name, it usually helps to do so though.

Comment: `Press(...).Button()`…?! If `Button` requires `self.T`, how is it supposed to work without instantiating `Press`?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm after. THANK YOU A LOT! 
P.S. I don't understand why would someone downvote my post, i didn't knew this, and now i found out. I'm a newbie to python, and this site helps me a lot.

Comment: The downvote is probably because your question showed no signs of research or experimentation.  You should do a _lot_ of research before asking a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: I did watched more than few tutorials for OOP in Python, but all of them were focused on other things rather than my question. I knew it was a "silly question" but i had to find out somehow, and stackoverflow was my last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you expect to achieve, but if you want to call `Button` in a single line of code you can do it this way:

```
Press(2, LONG_PRESS).Button(...)`
```

The way you've defined `Button`, you simply *must* create an instance of the class first since `Button` relies on `self.T`. There is no way to get at `self.T` without `self`, and there's no way to get `self` without creating an instance of the object.

Comment: Yes, like i said, i wanted to call the function and initialize the instance in one line. Thank you for your time!

Comment: but is there any other way to define Button ?

Comment: @MihaiBerci: yes, there are many ways to define your `Button` method. For example,  a simple function will do: `def Button(nr, T): ...`.

Comment: I need to use a Class, as the Button will have more functions